# How do I find Bluetooth connections in Mac system logs

Tags: macos, logging, bluetooth

I've lost my BT earphones, and am trying to determine the last time they were connected to my macbook, to narrow the time window and help the search.

How can I learn this from system logs?

I opened Console.app, and found numerous mentions of connections to BT devices, of the format:

> com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.bluetooth.connect
>   com.apple.message.host: 05AC8290
>   com.apple.message.process: blued
>   com.apple.message.device: Unknown Name
>   com.apple.message.uuid: 0x001F
>   com.apple.message.direction: Outgoing
>   com.apple.message.rssi: 127
>   com.apple.message.pairing: LE
>   com.apple.message.rate: LE
>   com.apple.message.sco: LE
>   SenderMachUUID: 557AF7B3-7829-380F-83D7-684B2004E540

How do I determine which ones are connections to my BT earphones (not my smartphone)? I know the MAC addresses of both the devices that connect to this computer, but they don't seem to be mentioned in the logs.

Answer (score 7):

Hold `shift` and `option` buttons at the same time and click on the Bluetooth icon:
[image]

Click on the Debug and then click on Enable Bluetooth logging. Then in the magnifier type "Console". In the search area, search for Bluetooth. You should be able to see the logs:
[image]

Comment: This seems to have been removed in macos

Comment: @FooBar: I also do not have the "Enable Bluetooth logging" option in the menu, but opening Console and filtering for Bluetooth did show interesting entries.

Comment: Install the Bluetooth logging profile from developer.apple.com and download PacketLogger.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check Bluetooth logs open the Console.app e.g. by pressing `cmd` + `space`, then typing "Console" and hitting `Enter`.
[image]
Inside the Console.app you can filter messages just to Bluetooth related by typing "bluetooth" inside Search field.

Tested on macOS Catalina.